# Prove using Implicit Function Theorem, that the equation $u^3-2u^2+uv+\operatorname{Id}=0$ has a solution for $|v|$ small enough

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, multilinear-algebra

I want to prove that the equation \begin{align}u^3-2u^2+uv+\operatorname{Id}=0\end{align} has a solution for $|v|$ small enough. My goal is to use  Implicit Function Theorem. I assume that the matrices are of $n\times n$ dimension.

Implicit Function Theorem states that

Let $U$ be open in $\Bbb{R}^n,$ $V$ open in $\Bbb{R}^m$. Let \begin{align}f:U\times V\to \Bbb{R}^m\end{align}
\begin{align}(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)\end{align}
be a $C^K$ function. Assume there exists $(a,b)\in U\times V$ for which $f(a,b)=0$ and $D_y f(a,b)\in GL(\Bbb{R}^m).$ Then, there exists $U_1\subset U$ an open neighborhood of $a$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$, $U_2\subset V$ an open neighborhood of $b$ in $\Bbb{R}^m$ and a $C^K$ function $\varphi:U_1\to U_2$ such that \begin{align}f(x,y)=0\leftrightarrow y=\varphi(x)\end{align}
for $(x,y)\in U_1\times U_2.$

Please, how do I go about this? Any help?

Comment: for $v = 0, u = 1$ is indeed a solution.

Comment: Have you tried some version of the implicit function theorem? Are these $n \times n$?

Comment: @4-ier: No, I have not! But I'm interested in the use of implicit function theorem!

Comment: I would suggest looking into it, using pointguard0's suggested point.

Comment: @4-ier: I think IFT would be better since our lecturer is teaching us wants to teach us IFT. He wants us to research and find out the solution.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. To use the IFT, you have to have a specfied base point and calculate the jacobian there with respect to one of the variables.

Comment: @4-ier: I'll love if you can render any help on it!

Comment: Well, try what you can and modify your question with what you did and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: @4-ier: Thanks!

Comment: @4-ier: Kindly check if the topic is correct and if not, please let me know. You can even edit yourself! Atleast, you know what I want!

Comment: Well, I would try to encode the matrix corrdinates (u,v) as an element of \R^{d} for some d. Then try to work out what the IFT want you to work out. Remember you don't have to calculate the whole Jacobian, just part of it.

Comment: @4-ier: Alright, I'm waiting!

Comment: Waiting for what? You should try to do what I suggested.

Comment: @4-ier: Okay, if I may ask. What is $R^{d}$ in this case?

Comment: $R^d$ is the set of coordinates (x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots, x_{d-1}, x_d)$. What did you learn that the IFT says?

Comment: @Mike - I am going to be annoying (again): Post ALL your work, don't expect other people to do it for you. Show them ALL your efforts so a) they can see what the extent of your knowledge is and b) not come out as someone who just wants their homework questions answered. You've been 
on this site for long enough time to know what the procedure is.

Comment: @asdf: I made some edits!

Comment: @Mike There still aren't any efforts posted, just the statement...

Comment: @asdf; I'm yet to be taught it! That would be in the next class. I just have to research it.

Comment: Interesting fact is that this also happens to hold if $v$ is symmetric, regardless of how large $|v|$ is.  Not sure that will help you here, though.

Comment: @Mike All I'm saying is that you've not posted what you have done. Your work. Your attempts. Your thoughts. Those are just statements. I don't want to be too rude, but asking people to do your homework without showing attempts is not the best behaviour.